# Getting parameters of a generic function

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a class that will accept a `factory` function in it's `constructor` parameters and use it to crate instances of another class. This is how it looks in Javascript.

```js
// item to create
class Item{}

function factory(someData){
 return new Item()
}

class Repository{
  constructor(factory){
     this.factory = factory
  }

  createItem(optionalData){
   return this.factory(optionalData)
 }
}
```

Now, the `Repository` class should accept a `generic` item, and the factory function should satisfy a constraint that it creates that generic item.

The place where I'm struggling is **extracting** the `factory` prop parameters and using them as parameters to the `createItem` method. I need the `createItem` method to mimic the arguments of the `factory` function.

```
class Item {
  constructor(public data:{id:string,name:string}){
  }
}

// my attempt to type factory function
export type ModelFactory<TModel> = (...args:any[]) => TModel


class Collection<TModel >{

  constructor(public factory:ModelFactory<TModel>){}

  // my attempt to extract factory function parameters
  createItem(data?:Parameters<ConstructorParameters<typeof Collection>[0]>[0]){
    return this.factory(data)
  }
}

// implementation
const createItemFactory:ModelFactory<Item> = function (data:{id:string,name:string}){
  return new Item(data)
}

const coll = new Collection<Item>(createItemFactory)

// arguments to createItem() should be strongly typed
const itemInstance = coll.createItem(1)
```

Problems:

- When I call `coll.createItem()` arguments are typed as `any`
- `factory` function could have a signature with no arguments.

I'm struggling to cover these scenarios.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECSAuBTAttA3gWAFDWsA9gHYTwBOArsPPqQBQAO5ARiAJbDQAmY8YAXGlac+JUq0IBzADSEwyRCLLiJAXwCUmHNBXYdWbAHoD0ZAE9oPJMnrxo1O6fqJoAMzBUa5l+UJVWRbEQAD3oaW3hHZwBZfE5EEAAxd2pSUwAeABUYuJAAPmgAXmhaADoysFIJCD4wQlMAbQBdNUL8rNj47C6sUEgYAGF8EBBEPyJM7PjoXM1sXAJiMkoUhmY2DjcPVL5JxOTPCY68jT056CMTc0sUGzt8aGCyZNd91NcfMcJoegq5RCRSBAzsBSIgeIgEChaNxeAB+PgABV+8gBEDSg0WFC2SNIf1RaQiTnwLmgg2Go3g-kIuXqAAZGjT6RozrhQfByKQvvAABasCAlTYpUzQnhgNRnPSnLAXVjWEbyQi8SkBHpEEh4UHgyHIJJbUw7I66oVpbX5IreXzKr4i3gCISKMSSGR-B3KdSaVn-DlfQiIADucCsNrFum6C3VBGGhWgvoDZJGnxNVlytBBYKQ2qNnnFqsW0FYVlgi1qwGcRUjIBKaa1QYAjC0LhUJOQFfAYBBufhyCBONAmM5REQJCBzITEL3aBA-hYYILPO9LVS1EA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably make `Collection` generic *both* in `factory`'s return type (you're calling this `TModel` and I will call it just `T`) and also in the *argument list* [rest tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types) (I will call this `A`):

```
class Collection<A extends any[], T>{
  constructor(public factory: (...args: A) => T) { }
  createItem(...args: A) {
    return this.factory(...args)
  }
}
```

Note how I call `this.factory()` with spread syntax.  Using rest/spread here takes care of the maybe-zero and maybe-one argument issue, as well as supporting functions which take any number of arguments.  Let's try it out:

```
const coll = new Collection(createItemFactory)
coll.createItem(1); // error!
// Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ id: string; name: string; }'
const itemInstance = coll.createItem({ id: "a", name: "b" }) // okay


// no args
const c2 = new Collection(() => ({ a: 123 }));
console.log(c2.createItem().a.toFixed(2)); // 123.00

// more than one args
const c3 = new Collection((x: number, y: string) => ({ x, y }));
console.log(c3.createItem(1, "b")); // {x: 1, y: "b"}
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-n1yyIHIgfCSamNhMcm49xY5ai3ViuRCcWiNzT8gtD0c5AAMp4rQuQNEtYx8TvhNc69fxY5erdJlg7lK7tFcAk1ZBtVIWQsn9IFJF7L5alcUDxz5SdrBnOdqRHJc6S5blZFTXMDwFIU0H-IdQJzVNDCAA)

Comment: Looks very good :) Can you please explain why my version of extracting factory types doesn't work, since I believe that technically I'm doing the right thing.

Comment: You are tossing away the information about the factory function parameters by using `(...args: any[])`.  With your code, when you call `const coll = new Collection(createItemFactory)`, then `coll` is a `Collection<Item>`.  If you called `const otherColl = new Collection((name: string) => new Item({ id: "", name: name }))` then `otherColl` would *also* be a `Collection<Item>`.  Those are the same exact type.  So the compiler has no way to know that `coll.createItem` expects one param type and `otherColl.createIem` expects another.